# Smart contract transaction of 0 XTZ throwing error from TezBox

Tags: smart-contracts, tezbox

I am trying to send transaction to KT1BRudFZEXLYANgmZTka1xCDN5nWTMWY7SZ to complete ledger nano verification using TezBox but I am getting error as below, can someone please guide me?

```
{"status":"failed","errors":[{"kind":"temporary","id":"proto.004-Pt24m4xi.gas_exhausted.operation"}]}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same error on an old T3wallet.com web wallet I had a few XTZ on when trying to move them. I changed the fee and gas limit as suggested above but didn't work. Maybe this wallet is dead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did not change the Gas Limit parameter. Default value is 10600, you need [13025](https://tezos.foundation/news/tezos-foundation-to-give-away-ledger-nano-s-hardware-wallets-to-celebrate-one-year-since-betanet-launch).

> 3. From the Send interface with Advanced Options displayed, input the following information:
>
> Destination Address: KT1BRudFZEXLYANgmZTka1xCDN5nWTMWY7SZ
>
> Amount: 0
>
> XTZ Fee (recommended): Medium – 5000 Parameters:      (Leave empty)
>
> **Gas limit: 13,025**
>
> Storage limit: 300

This too-low limit causes the "gas_exhausted" error.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.